# Include template file in an HTML file, similar to CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, html-imports, html5-template

I am working with HTML `<template>` elements. Code-wise, it seems inconvenient to keep the correct set of templates inside each HTML file.

Is it possible to put templates in a separate file? I want something like CSS, where I can include CSS files in the `<head>` section of my HTML file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

My app uses several `<template>` collections. Can they be in a separate file, or does each `<template>` definition need to be directly part of the original HTML file?

Comment: Can you please add more information - I don't really understand the question.

Comment: you can look into jade or javascript frameworks that allow templating - angularjs, for example. react and emberjs are also popular, and i believe they support templating as well.

Comment: @Marty - I think this is clearer

Comment: @harmlessdragon - I think html5 templates are well supported. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template and http://caniuse.com/#feat=template. for me, angular is a nightmare. attempting now to my own react-inspired controller/component/store using templates and web services

Comment: @ccyoung once I saw an answer come in, I knew I would learn something. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**2020 Update**

Now that HTML Imports have been deprecated, you could use `fetch()` to download HTML code:

```
void async function () {
    //get the imported document in templates:
    var templates = document.createElement( 'template' )
    templates.innerHTML = await ( await fetch( 'templates.html' ) ).text()

    //fetch template2 1 and 2:
    var template1 = templates.content.querySelector( '#t1' ) 
    var template2 = templates.content.querySelector( '#t2' ) 
    console.log( template2 )
} ()
```

---

**Original answer**

Imagine we want to import a bunch of `<template>`s in a separate file called *templates.html*.

In the (main) homepage *index.html*, we can import the file via HTML Imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="templates.html" id="templates">
```

In the imported file *templates.html*, add one or as many templates as you need:

```
<template id="t1">
     <div>content for template 1</div>
</template>

<template id="t2">
     content for template 2
</template>
```

The imported document is available from the `import` property of the `<link>` element. You can use `querySelector` on it.

```
<script>
  //get the imported document in doc:
  var link = document.querySelector( 'link#templates' )
  var doc = link.import

  //fetch template2 1 and 2:
  var template1 = doc.querySelector( '#t1' )
  var template2 = doc.querySelector( '#t2' )
</script>
```

**Note:** you can place the above script in the main document, or in the imported one because the `<script>`s inside an imported file are executed as soon as the are parsed (at download time).

Comment: Unfortunately, HTML imports [have been deprecated](https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports)...

Comment: @sunnymoon yes now you should use fetch(), that you could encapsulate in an extended customized link element for example

Comment: Please, post an update _above_ the obsolete content

Answer (score 5):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

You need HTML 5 though

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```

Comment: yes, this puts a template into the html file. what I'm after is storing the templates in a separate file, much like a stylesheet puts styles into a separate file, for sanity.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity - yes, as usual. but it seems edge is compliant.

Comment: However with this browser support is still limited. http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Comment: @Mi-Creativity - you're right - `import` is what's needed here. can you add it as answer? if not, I'll put it as answer tomorrow to document. thanks

Comment: @ccyoung, it was Abs who suggested `import` not me, i just showed the link of its current support

Comment: @Abs, you have already got my upvote since the `<template>` :)

Comment: nice in theory, but afaik does not work in practice. see next answer.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately,

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```

does *not* work.

The entire `stuff.html` is stuck in there as `html` as part of `head`, and for all practicable purposes inaccessible.

In other words, a `template defined in`stuff.html`cannot be found using`document.querySelector()`, and is therefore unavailable to the script.

fwiw, I don't really understand any advantages of `import` the way it works now - for it to be any good it needs to strip off (rather than adding) all the outer html before it appends the contents to `head` - not its current action.

Comment: Actually you can access the content of an imported HTML file by using the import property of the link element.

Comment: @Supersharp can you give an example using `document.querySelector()`?