# Memory Consumption When Placing Style in Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom, ecmascript-2018

I haven't found any information on memory consumption when placing CSS style in [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

What if I have a thousand instances of a particular [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) on a page (each with style via shadow root); would that embedded style take up a 999 times as much memory as doing the same styling via an external style sheet?

Comment: @Supersharp : Ok, so in summary, it would indeed consume 999 times as much memory as doing the same styling via an external style sheet? This is a bit tricky. On one hand, I know that even with an external style sheet the styles must be applied to each element, but I'm not sure if styling in the Shadow DOM would necessarily consume more memory after instantiation. It seems possible that a browser implementation could store the styling at a static class-level instead of on each instance, but in practice I have no experience comparing the memory footprint of each methodology.

Comment: The inline `<style>` DOM elements will be duplicated 999 times compared to an external stylesheet, which sould takes in memory the size of a little picture. The CSS properties will be applied to every DOM element. Using classes to save memory would be very tricky to implement and manage, and slow to update dynamically. The challenge for a rendering engine is fast and accurate rendering, not memory consumption.